# How to deep copy data from completionHandler clousure to ViewController class in Swift?

Tags: swift, completionhandler

I've tried to DeepCopy data with NSCopying protocol and with JSON decoder/encoder, but everytime I stumble upon somewhere and can't get it fixxed.

How can I copy exactly the same all of the contents from result to class variable postData? I'd like to add it to tableview programaticly but I just can't get it to work.

Here is ViewController class code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
       
    
    var postData:[Post] = []
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        DataLoader.shared.fetchPostData(completionHandler: {
            result in
            //it prints result here
            for x in result{
                print(x.id!)
            }
            
            self.postData = result
            
        })
        
        //I'd like to print it here
        for x in self.postData{
            print(x.id!)
        }
    }
```

Here is Post class code:

```
import Foundation

struct Post: Decodable{
    var userId: Int!
    var id: Int!
    var title: String!
    var body: String!
}
```

and here is DataLoader class code:

```
import Foundation


class DataLoader: Codable {
    
    //var classData:[Post] = []
    static let shared = DataLoader()
    
    func fetchPostData(completionHandler: @escaping ([Post]) -> Void){
        let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data else { return }
        
        
        do {
            let postsData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)
            //self.classData = postsData
            completionHandler(postsData)
            
        }
        catch {
            let error = error
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            //completionHandler(nil)
        }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the asynchrone concept. If you noticed, when you do "//it prints result here" and "//I'd like to print it here", in fact if there was data the "//it prints result here" would be printed AFTER. It's not "linear" (line after line), the closure will be called later. So Inside the closure, once you get the data, do `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.postData = result; self.tableView.reloadData() }`

Comment: Unrelated, but `print(error.localizedDescription)` => `print(error)`, because if there is a error throws by `decode(_:from:)` it will be more helpful than the `localizedDescription` more for user than developers...